# Bootstrap scrollspy along with angular custom-directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Can anyone help me. I'm stuck with the following issue. I have a normal page with the `scrollspy` activated for the navigation bar. Everything is fine, but I created a `custom directive` for my navigation bar and when I load the navigation bar using this new custom directive, ScrollSpy and smooth scrolling do not work!!!

**index.html:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".myScroll" data-offset="60">

    <navigation-bar></navigation-bar>

</body>
```

**Navigation-bar.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top myScroll" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html#myPage">My Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="index.html#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="signup.html">Sign-up</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
    </div>      
</nav>
```

**Custom Directive**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("navigationBar", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'navigation-bar.html'
    };
});
```

**JS file for smooth scrolling**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar a").on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 1000, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel obliged to add that this is a kinda hacky way to add scrollspy support to an Angular application but doing it the correct way following all the best practices might be too much for an answer.

The problem is that when the scrollspy plugin initializes the page doesn't contain the navbar yet. Try removing the data-scrollspy from the body and adding the scrollspy initialization into the directive's link function

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("navigationBar", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'navigation-bar.html',
        link: function() { 
          $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.myScroll', offset: 60 }); 
          $(".navbar a").on('click', function(event) {
            if (this.hash !== "") {
              event.preventDefault();
              var hash = this.hash;
              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
              }, 1000, function(){
                  window.location.hash = hash;
              });
            }
          });
        }
    };
});
```

EDIT: this plunker works, even with the click animation http://plnkr.co/edit/2877Zf?p=preview

Mind that if new links get added at runtime the onclick event will not work on them, in order to do that you must use event delegation:

```
$("body").on('click', ".navbar a" ,function(event) {
  if (this.hash !== "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 1000, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @valepu , but unfortunately it is not working!

Comment: It should be working, see this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/2877Zf?p=preview i added the animation onclick

Comment: glad i've been of help